# gunicorn with inotify is not noticing changed files with reload

Tags: python, gunicorn, inotify

I have a Flask app that I'm running for development in a Docker container, using gunicorn (v19.9.0). I've installed the [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) module to see if it's quicker for gunicorn's `--reload` option than the default polling method, but it doesn't seem to notice file changes.

If I start gunicorn with this:

```sh
gunicorn --reload --reload-engine=poll -b 0.0.0.0:5006 wsgi:app --workers=4 --timeout=600
```

then if I make a change to a python file (like a Flask view), the logs show "Worker reloading" 4 times. Once the workers have rebooted, then when I refresh the page in my browser the code changes are picked up.

But if I specify the inotify reload engine:

```sh
gunicorn --reload --reload-engine=inotify -b 0.0.0.0:5006 wsgi:app --workers=4 --timeout=600
```

and change the contents of files, there's no "Worker reloading" or rebooting in the logs. And when I reload a page, the changes aren't present.

I feel like I've missed something obvious...?

Comment: Having added some debugging to a copy of gunicorn, it's not adding the directory in which all my code lives to the list of directories it watches with inotify. No idea why.